# Passing a session between two html pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I am trying to pass a session between two html pages,

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$sname = $row["SP_Name"];
$sname = ucfirst($sname);
$sprice1 = $row["SP_Price1"];
$sprice1 = ucfirst($sprice1);
$_SESSION["sprice1"] = $sprice1;
echo "<tr><td>".'<a  class="btn btn-success" href="pym.html" value="$sprice1">'.$row["SP_Price1"].'</a>'."</tr></td>";
```

in the second page, I am trying to use this value for the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var temp = "<?php session_start(); echo($_SESSION['sprice1']); ?>";
  var price = temp;

  var gst = .18;
  var k = Number(price)*Number(gst);
  var total = Number(price)+Number(k)
  document.getElementById("gstprice").innerHTML =k.toFixed(1);
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML =total.toFixed(1);
  document.getElementById("sprice").innerHTML = price;
</script>
```

but the value is not passing and the var Price is coming as empty

Comment: you didn't call `session_start()` on the first page.

Comment: Why using html pages? can't you just rename them to .php? and start_session() on each page and you are done?

Comment: You need to call session_start() in your code in the first page too.

Comment: now, i have called it but still it is the same and I have renamed the files to ,php but that is also not working. I have tried the command <?php session_start(); echo($_SESSION['sprice1']); ?> outside JS and it is working

Comment: by putting your <?php ... ?> insdie double quote on the second page, PHP won't execute those script, remove those double quote.

Comment: i removed that still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

start session every pages where you use `session['name'];` tag

```
<?php
session_start();

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$sname = $row["SP_Name"];
$sname = ucfirst($sname);
$sprice1 = $row["SP_Price1"];
$sprice1 = ucfirst($sprice1);
$_SESSION["sprice1"] = $sprice1;
echo "<tr><td>".'<a  class="btn btn-success" href="pym.html" value="$sprice1">'.$row["SP_Price1"].'</a>'."</tr></td>";
?>
```

**html page**

```
<?php session_start(); ?> 
<html>
//
//
</html>
```

Comment: thank you!, now when i pass <?php session_start(); echo($_SESSION['sprice1']); ?> inside HTML it is working but data is not getting pulled inside JS

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo 'var msg = "'.json_encode($_SESSION['msg']).'";';
</script>`